# Learning personal history of Asmus Nicolai Clausen?

Tags: germany, 20th-century, military-records, vital-records, locating-records

I am researching the history of Asmus Nicolai Clausen, originally from Flensburg in Germany, born 2 June 1911. He was the commander of the U-182, which was sunk on 16 May 1943, when he died. His father was also Asmus and died on 29 May 1936. His mother was called Magda - maiden name Palaudt. He was married but I do not know her name.

How can I learn more about his family?

Comment: You may already have this (for all I know, this is your website).  It says he's married and gives his parents' names.  http://collectinghistory.net/U-182/wehrpass.html

Comment: Have you checked with these folks? http://www.flensburg.de/Politik-Verwaltung/Stadtverwaltung/Stadtarchiv

Comment: Hi Gareth, of course you can always edit your own posts, I was just surprised to see you do so from a second account (the system couldn't tell you were the same person, which is why you had to get the edit approved).  I suggest you merge the two accounts.  If you can't do so yourself, one of the moderators can help.  @PolyGeo

Comment: As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: What specifically do you wish to learn about his family?  A specific question might be "How can I determine whether U-boat captain was married?"

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! You are likely to get better answers if you ask specific research questions. Questions like "How do I learn more?" invite similarly vague answers such as "Do research."